# How to get the size of a text file created with fwrite in php

Tags: php, fwrite, filesize

I have a php page that creates txt files using fwrite which are then uploaded to a directory on the server. I also have a mysql database that the URL for the file  is written to, is it possible to get the file size of the said file and add this to the database? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you save your file you know the path of the file try to get normally the filesize

```
$filename = 'directory_upload/somefile.txt';
$filesize = filesize($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [filesize](https://www.php.net/filesize)() function.